# Reuse Functionality of bar button item in View controllers in Tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How can I reuse functionality of bar button item (added programmatically) in view controllers in Tab bar?

[image]

Also, I want to show bar button items (added programmatically) in other view controller in navigation bars. I want to reuse code written in first view controller in other four view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the top portion in every screen.
The best way to do this is:

1) Create a uiviewcontroller- TOPBARVIEWCONTROLLER : UIViewController & add the buttons n stuff u want in your topbar.

eg,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *headerLBL;
-(void)setHeaderTitle:(NSString *)strHeading;
```

2) Now in the other viewController class where you want the topbar,

```
#import "TOPBARVIEWCONTROLLER.h"
```

instead of using: picgramViewcotroller: UIViewController
use: picgramViewcotroller: TOPBARVIEWCONTROLLER
 in .h file

in .m file, in viewdidload, call:

```
[self setHeaderTitle:@"New header title"];
```

Comment: @interface ASNPhotos:TopbarViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UIAlertViewDelegate> i am getting error "cannot find interface declaration for supperclass " even i import Topbarcontroller . other classes it works fine

Comment: you have to synthesize "headerLBL" and add this into .m file of topbatviewcontroller ::: -(void)setHeaderTitle:(NSString *)strHeading{
    
    [self.lblHeader setText:strHeading];
}

Comment: not working still "cannot find interface declaration for supperclass " error.